# Boot-time service startup messages are repeated a second time

Tags: fedora, systemd, plymouth

At boot time, I get a graphical activity indicator ("throbber" :).  Hitting ESC shows a more traditional stream of text lines like

```
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

However most of these seem to be repeated a second time.  And I'm not talking about the additional "Starting" line.  It looks like

```
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

Also occasionally the two streams of messages will appear to interrupt each other, i.e. two lines are mixed together.  Is this a bug in systemd?  Or in the plymouth boot display?

EDIT: The repetitions don't show up in `/var/log/boot.log` (generated by plymouth, includes the escape sequences used to color "OK" in green).  So it seems more like an issue with the plymouth display.

EDIT: Sometimes this happens, sometimes it doesn't.  As well as affecting the service start messages, it also seems to affect the message and progress % printed by offline updates ("restart and update" from GNOME).

Also it doesn't happen if I remove `rhgb` or both `rhgb` and `quiet` options from the kernel command line.  I don't see it in a VM (virt-manager); it doesn't look like the graphical boot splash works in there at all.

System: Fedora Linux 25 / 26.  I haven't customized the boot display on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a plymouth bug.

Partly based on the updated question, but I've just now tried booting with `plymouth.debug`.  For some reason it seems to have two "pixel displays" for my one screen, and both appear to be associated with a handle to `tty1`...

It looks like a fix for this has been committed upstream, yay! https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104353

```
[ply-keyboard.c:213]                        process_keyboard_input:escape key!
[main.c:1485]                             on_escape_pressed:escape key pressed
[main.c:1465]             toggle_between_splash_and_details:toggling between splash and details
[main.c:1467]             toggle_between_splash_and_details:hiding and freeing current splash
[ply-event-loop.c:965]      ply_event_loop_stop_watching_for_timeout:no matching timeout found for removal
[./plugin.c:1195]                            hide_splash_screen:hiding splash
[./plugin.c:818]                                stop_animation:stopping animation
[./plugin.c:831]                                stop_animation:hiding progress animation
[ply-animation.c:357]                            ply_animation_stop:animation already stopped, ignoring stop request
[./plugin.c:831]                                stop_animation:hiding progress animation
[ply-animation.c:357]                            ply_animation_stop:animation already stopped, ignoring stop request
[ply-boot-splash.c:388]                          ply_boot_splash_free:freeing splash
[ply-event-loop.c:965]      ply_event_loop_stop_watching_for_timeout:no matching timeout found for removal
[ply-boot-splash.c:333]                         remove_pixel_displays:removing pixel displays
[ply-boot-splash.c:347]                         remove_pixel_displays:Removing 1366x768 pixel display
[./plugin.c:1014]                          remove_pixel_display:removing pixel display from plugin
[ply-boot-splash.c:347]                         remove_pixel_displays:Removing 1366x768 pixel display
[./plugin.c:1014]                          remove_pixel_display:removing pixel display from plugin
[./plugin.c:700]                                destroy_plugin:destroying plugin
[./plugin.c:673]                                    free_views:freeing views
[main.c:352]                          show_detailed_splash:Showing detailed splash screen
[main.c:1655]                           load_built_in_theme:Loading built-in theme
[plugins/splash/details/plugin.c:156]                                 create_plugin:creating plugin
[main.c:1670]                           load_built_in_theme:attaching plugin to event loop
[main.c:1673]                           load_built_in_theme:attaching progress to plugin
[ply-boot-splash.c:174]              ply_boot_splash_add_text_display:adding 170x48 text display
[ply-terminal.c:598]                             ply_terminal_open:terminal /dev/tty1 is already open
[ply-boot-splash.c:174]              ply_boot_splash_add_text_display:adding 170x48 text display
[ply-terminal.c:598]                             ply_terminal_open:terminal /dev/tty1 is already open
```